# Recreating a day-night effect on an earth model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, lighting

I am trying to recreate an effect similar to the one in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02OswScn6AI), I have a model of the Satellite and I have worked on an earth model that is decent, the objective is to have an animation that mirrors the one in the video as close a possible (from light to dark with the ocean on the background) ,  I still can't get the day night effect and the intense lighting reflected off of the ocean.

[image: Here is a shot of what I have now]

Comment: Could you add another screenshot or two of the exact problem you're seeing?  Where exactly is your lighting model failing?  From your screenshot it looks like you've obtained some sort of "intense lighting reflected off of the ocean."

Comment: If you'd like, you can also upload your .blend file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for the response bertmoog, I want to create an animation similar to the one in the video, I might have gotten something close in regards to lighting but the day-light gradual transition is what I am completely clueless about, I will gladly upload my blend file when  I Am back in the office on Monday, but for now I can give you an idea of what I have, I have the model of the sat and a complete model of Earth, I set an ocean texture to high emission and that's what you see in the picture.